# The texts in the email signature are scrolling on the mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I was doing email signatures for my team. In fact, the email signatures I made on the computer look fine, but when I look at them from the phone, the texts of the fields such as name, title, address scroll upside down. I don't want it to be like this. I tried using whitespace-nowrap or something but it gave no results. Can you help me to solve this slipping problem?

I'm attaching the html code of the email signature below, you can check it out there.

```
<html>

<div id=":1wk" class="IO">
    <table cellpadding="0" class="An" id=":1zt">
        <tbody style="background-color: white;">
            <tr>
                <td class="Ap">
                    <div id=":1zy" class="IN" style="display: block;">
                        <div id=":1zz" class="Am aiL IP Al editable Xp0HJf-LW-avf" hidefocus="true"
                            aria-label="Signature" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"
                            contenteditable="true" style="direction: ltr;">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="https://resmim.net/cdn/2023/06/14/SHWbIh.png"
                                                style="margin:15px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;width:140px;height:130px">
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="https://omnicourse.io/" target="_blank"><img
                                                        src="https://i.hizliresim.com/ij4d0ab.png"
                                                        style="margin:10px 10px 10px 40px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;width:110px;height:20px"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                </td>
                <td style="padding-left:15px">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style="padding:0px;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-stretch:normal;line-height:normal;padding:0px 0px 4px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;color:rgb(31,25,90);font-size:13px;font-weight:bold">
                                    Selin Sena Akdeniz</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style="white-space: nowrap font-stretch:normal;line-height:normal;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:17px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;color:rgb(254,51,43)">
                                    Creator Relations Expert</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:8px">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/selinsenaakdeniz/"
                                                        target="_blank"><img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/rel1rvt.png"
                                                            style="width:20px;height:20px"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><a href="https://twitter.com/SelinSAkdeniz" target="_blank"><img
                                                            src="https://resmim.net/cdn/2023/06/14/SHfn8Q.png"
                                                            style="width:20px;height:20px"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><a href="https://ssenaakdeniz.medium.com/" target="_blank"><img
                                                            src="https://resmim.net/cdn/2023/06/14/SHf9O3.png"
                                                            style="width:20px;height:20px"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style="width:164px;line-height:normal;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;margin-bottom:5px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;color:rgb(31,25,90);font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">
                                    <a href="mailto:selin@omnicourse.io" target="_blank">selin@omnicourse.io</a>
                                </td>
                                <td><img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/azo380f.png"
                                        style="height:40px;margin-right:14px"></td>
                                <td
                                    style="white-space: nowrap line-height:normal;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;border-spacing:0px;color:rgb(31,25,90);font-size:13px">
                                    16192 Coastal Hwy, Lewes,<br>Delaware 19958, US <br></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: What is "scroll upside down" supposed to mean?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap font-stretch:normal` There's no semicolon between these properties.

Comment: @Havalanmak I did as you said and I put them like this `style="padding:0px;white-space:nowrap;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-stretch:normal;` however, when I add the signature from gmail and send it, when I check it from the phone, text fields such as name and title still appear. Do you have another suggestion?